# Nextjs Link with local image path component produces a 404 error log in the console

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

The URL of the local image has been added to the next `Link` component. It logs a 404 error in the console although when I open the link inside the console it displays the image without any problems

```
<Link target="_blank" href="/images/projects/zamir/1.png">
  <Image
    width={500}
    height={500}
    src="/images/projects/zamir/1.png"
 />
</Link>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding in a full URL in the link tag

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is happening because Next.js fails to preload non-existent router path.

I can think of 2 ways to avoid this error:

1. Add `prefetch={false}` prop to the `<Link>` tag
2. Use standard `<a>` tag instead of `<Link>` since there is no added benefit in using `next/link` for external or `target="_blank"` links

Comment: yes i use <a> tag instead of <Link> and fix the issue. but i'm curious what cause this issue

Comment: In your case `<Link>` component is trying to prefetch a page, and that page obviously doesn’t exist.